# rails3 rails.js and jquery catching success and failure of ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Previously, in rails 2.3.8 i used the prototype-helpers `link_to_remote` and `form_remote_for` (amongst others).

These had the option `:update` as follows:

```
link_to_remote "Add to cart",
  :url => { :action => "add", :id => product.id },
  :update => { :success => "cart", :failure => "error" }
```

(an example from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html)).
This example would, upon success update the html-element with class "cart", and upon failure the class "error".

Now i believe the modus operandi has changed, instead we write:

```
link_to "Add to cart", :url => {:action => "add", :id => product.id}, 
    :remote => true
```

and there is no option to set `:update` anymore.
Instead of a normal html, we now render javascript, like this (in jquery) :

```
$('.cart').replaceWith(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cart') %>)
```

but how do you handle an error situation?
Do i handle it in my controller, and use seperate views?

It would seem useful to me to somehow be able to mimic the behaviour we had before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Ha! I found it described in [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) article. In rails.js the following callbacks are checked:

- ajax:loading : triggered before executing the AJAX request
- ajax:success : triggered after a successful AJAX request
- ajax:complete : triggered after the AJAX request is complete, regardless the status of the response
- ajax:failure : triggered after a failed AJAX request, as opposite to ajax:success

As the javascript should be unobtrusive, this coupling is not done in the HTML.

An example (from the same site) : the following Rails 2.3.8

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { :action => 'run' },
        :id => "tool-form",
        :update => { :success => "response", :failure => "error" },
        :loading => "$('#loading').toggle()", :complete => "$('#loading').toggle()" %>
```

is translated to this :

```
<% form_tag url_for(:action => "run"), :id => "tool-form", :remote => true do %>
```

and inside some javascript (application.js), you bind the events

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // create a convenient toggleLoading function
  var toggleLoading = function() { $("#loading").toggle() };

  $("#tool-form")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
      $("#response").html(status);
    });
});
```

Great! :)

[UPDATE: 29/12/2011]

Two events have been renamed lately:

- `ajax:beforeSend`: replace the late `ajax:loading`
- `ajax:error` replaces the `ajax:failure` (I guess to be more in line with jQuery itself)

So my example would become:

```
  $("#tool-form")
    .bind("ajax:beforeSend",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
      $("#response").html(status);
    });
```

For completeness, the events and their expected parameters:

```
 .bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {})
 .bind('ajax:success',    function(xhr, data, status) {})
 .bind('ajax:complete', function(xhr, status) {})
 .bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, data, status) {})
```

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks they took a step back with removing simple javascript from Rails?

Comment: Like css splits much of the layouting from the content (HTML), it is also better to split the behaviour from the HTML (so use unobtrusive js). While this is, indeed, harder (at first), it also makes your HTML/JS easier to read (use your class-names and identifiers wisely), and makes your JS easier to maintain and re-use in the longrun.

Comment: 'ajax:loading' did not work for me, I had to use 'ajax:before' - just in case anybody else encounters this problem. (Rails 3.1.1)

Comment: @Axsuul: please check the code of the [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) : there is no event variable triggered!

Comment: And for the latest jQuery rails callbacks see the GitHub page: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Answer (score 4):

The related rails 4 guide can be found at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

It points to the documentation of the events at: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax , as mentioned by ncherro

The actual values passed to the callbacks can be inferred from jQuery's `ajax` method http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

`.bind` is deprecated in favor of `.on` by jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/on/

So now the recommended approach is:

Template:

```
<%= link_to 'Click me!',
    'path/to/ajax',
    remote: true,
    id: 'button',
    method: :get,
    data: {type: 'text'}
%>
```

CoffeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#button").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    alert "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 3 years old, but it comes up high in Google results and some of the events listed above are not used anymore.

See here for a current list - https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax