# Rails 3 - form_for and success/failure callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've upgraded my app to Rails 3, and in the process I replaced form_remote_tag with form_for. I'm trying to set success and failure callbacks but they aren't working:

:html => { :success => 'onFormSuccess(request)', :failure => 'onFormFailure(request)' }

Does this not work with form_for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails3 rails.js and jquery catching success and failure of ajax requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501317/rails3-rails-js-and-jquery-catching-success-and-failure-of-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jquery? In that case i answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501317/rails3-rails-js-and-jquery-catching-success-and-failure-of-ajax-requests) :)