# Rails 3: How to make an Ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have a link (is there a better option?) on my page which will make an Ajax request when clicked. (I would like to update a field in my database when the link is clicked.)

What is the simplest way to achieve this ?

Could you refer me to some tutorials ?

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax

Comment: How to react to the response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501317/rails3-rails-js-and-jquery-catching-success-and-failure-of-ajax-requests/24431551#24431551

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Really simple. In your view, have a link/button like so. Important bit being *:remote => true*

```
<%= link_to 'Update Thingy', update_thingy_path, :confirm => 'You sure you wanna update?', :remote => true %>
```

or

```
<%= button_to('Update Thingy', {:action => 'update_thingy', :thingyid => 314}, :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
```

Obviously, you have to get update_thingy_path to resolve to some action as normal. The difference is when you render you are going to be rendering some *.js.erb instead of *.html.erb. In that update_thingy.js.erb, you just put whatever javascript you want to run in the client. You might wanna notify the user that the update happened for example (in jQuery):

```
$('#notice').html("Thingy was update.")
```

Or if whatever javascript you're returning is really simple, in the controller you can do something like the following instead of having a whole js.erb for a one-liner.

```
render :js => "alert('Blah')"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're really going to be using two technologies to accomplish this: javascript on the client-side, and rails on the server-side. 
The general idea is that you want to: 
(1) add your web methods on the server side with rails, and then 
(2) use something like jQuery to get your client-side js calls up to the server to fire off the web methods.

Two writeups I found by googling for :  rails3 ajax

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

API Reference for using jQuery's ajax post() method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/