# Rails Form_Tag remote call success but no jquery callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have a form_tag to make an ajax call to my search method which returns json.

```
= form_tag '/search',:remote => true,id: 'form', method: :post do
  = hidden_field_tag '_method,', :put 
  .row.form_attributes
    = text_field_tag :location, nil, placeholder: "San Francisco, CA"
    = submit_tag "Search", :class=>"btn btn-primary"
```

Here is the final statement in my controller action:

```
def search
  #irrelevant code 
  render json: stripped_events.to_json
end
```

I have setup the following listener so that I can take the returned json and manipulate it.

```
console.log("LOAD");
$('#form').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
  console.log("WIN");
  console.log(data);
});
```

I know my javascript is loading because I see "LOAD" printed on console. I have also tried following the discussion, [rails3 rails.js and jquery catching success and failure of ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501317/rails3-rails-js-and-jquery-catching-success-and-failure-of-ajax-requests), but had no success.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning JSON to the browser, you could respond with JavaScript instead:

```
def search
    #irrelevant code
    @stripped_events = ...

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

And then create a view template called `search.js.erb` in `app/views/controller_name`. This file is ERB-evaluated JavaScript, so you can use Ruby in it just like an HTML ERB template. The JavaScript in this file will be executed in the context of the browser.

```
console.log("WIN");
<% for stripped_event in @stripped_events %>
// use JavaScript / jQuery to manipulate the DOM
<% end %>
```