# Rails submit remote form and handle formless response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

When I submit my remote form, my controller returns a layout-less index view in HTML. I want to have a callback on the client that can be triggered when that index view is loaded in my HTML. I have tried things like:

```
$("form").bind('ajax:complete', function(xhr, status) { theCallback() });
```

But this does not work. Neither does binding `ajax:success`. Debugging in `jquery_ujs.js` lead me to believe that the problem is caused by the fact that the form to which the callback event is bound, is not present in the HTML response. So the element that is triggered is gone.

This does not seem like such an exotic scenario to me, so I'm guessing there must be a really simple solution for this. Especially, I'm hoping this can be done with the HTML response type. I'm sure it can be done with the JS response type...

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3501317/1065703). Binding to `ajax:success` should work. Can you check the response of the AJAX call (i.e. with firebug)

Comment: The response is the plain partial HMTL. And in `jquery_ujs.js` I see the `complete` callback being executed after the HMTL is returned, which executes this statement: `element.trigger('ajax:complete', [xhr, status]);`. However, `element` refers to the `$("form")` that does not exist anymore in the new HTML and thus my callback is never executed. 

To move forward, I decided to go with the JS response type and I execute the callback functionality explicitely in my response. But still I'm very eager to find the solution for the HTML response.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('form').bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr)
```